Publishing outgoing messages with Helidon and Oracle AQ
I have the following class that supposed to send messages to Oracle AQ defined application.yml.
@ApplicationScoped
public class BaseAQClient{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseAQClient.class);

    @Outgoing("to-aq-pokemon")
    public PublisherBuilder<String> publish(String msg) {
        PublisherBuilder<String> result = ReactiveStreams.of(msg);
        return result;
    }
    
    @Incoming("from-aq-pokemon")
    public void consumeAq(String msg) {
        logger.debug("Oracle AQ says: {}", msg);
    }
}

When I want to send message I do something like that
BaseAQClient client = new BaseAQClient ();

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> client.publish(message))
.thenApply(result -> {  logger.info("Message published successfully: {}", result);
                        return "Message published successfully: " + result;})
.exceptionally(e -> {logger.error("Error publishing message: {}", e.getMessage());
                     return "Error publishing message";});

It does not send messages at all and feels totally wrong to call the publishing method like this. But i can not find the correct way to do this. Also I do not need async option.

This question is similar to: Oracle AQ java implementation of enque/deque. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just to clarify for other readers, it's MicroProfile Reactive Messaging in Helidon 4 MP with Oracle AQ connector.
There are several things wrong:

It's a bean you can't instantiate it yourself

Never call messaging methods manually(there is a big exclamation mark in the docs)

If you are not familiar with reactive streams, it is better to stick with imperative messaging api(Emitter for sending messages)
@Path("/pokemons")
@ApplicationScoped
public class BaseAQClient {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseAQClient.class);

    @Inject
    @Channel("to-aq-pokemon")
    private Emitter<String> emitter;

    @PUT
    public Response publish(String message) {
        emitter.send(message);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @Incoming("from-aq-pokemon")
    public void consumeAq(String msg) {
        logger.debug("Oracle AQ says: {}", msg);
    }
}



